# Fraction mapped to sum and geometric mean approaches 2.1479

Tags: sequences-and-series, constants

Map a positive fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ to $\frac{a + b}{\sqrt{ab}}$.
Repeating seems to map every starting fraction to a
number close to $\xi = 2.1479$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{7}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{7+\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{7} \sqrt[4]{10}} & \frac{7+\sqrt{7} \sqrt[4]{10}+\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt[4]{7} \sqrt[8]{10} \sqrt{7+\sqrt{10}}} \\
 0.25 & 2.5 & 2.21359 & 2.15994 & 2.1501 \\
\end{array}
$$

> ***Q***. Does indeed every starting fraction approach $\xi\,$?
>   Is $\xi$ a known constant in other contexts?

---

This is a variation on an earlier post,
[Why does this process map every fraction to the golden ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3440647/237)

Comment: twice arithmetic mean over geometric mean.

Comment: That's surely not correct. Doing this with the OP's example would give $\frac{11}{2 \sqrt10} \approx 1.74$ ([Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2F4+%2B+5%2F2%29%2F2%29%2F%28sqrt%281%2F4+*+5%2F2%29%29)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$${a+b\over\sqrt{ab}}={(a/b)+1\over\sqrt{a/b}}$$ so you are mapping $x$ to $(x+1)/\sqrt x=x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}$. Fixed point should be solution of $x=x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}$. This is a cubic in $x$, $x^3-x^2-2x-1=0$.

Comment: Nice! The sole real root of that cubic $\approx 2.1478990$.